# регистрация в Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel

Доброго времени суток!
Подскажите кто знает, разбираюсь с регистрацией в Laravel 5.1
в routes.php добавлено

```
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
```

views есть и для логина и для регистрации
добавил админа (стандартного через seeds) авторизировался нормально, проблема с регистрацией, заполняю поля, а пользователь не добавляется, что то упускаю, но не пойму что, views для регистрации взял из документации

```
<form method="POST" action="/auth/register">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}

    <div>
        Name
        <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">
    </div>

    <div>
        Email
        <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
    </div>

    <div>
        Password
        <input type="password" name="password">
    </div>

    <div>
        Confirm Password
        <input type="password" name="password_confirmation">
    </div>

    <div>
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Я рекомендую использовать готовое решение из коробки Laravel Auth. Переделать под себя не составит вам большего труда. Выполните команду в консоли:

```
 php artisan make:auth
```

Подробней можете почитать тут:
[Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication)

Comment: это для 5.3 а у меня 5.1 и тоже является коробочной сборкой, используется, как я понимаю, тот же контроллер "Auth" -  Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister'); брал отсюда https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/authentication

Comment: хорошо, отдебаште контролер с регистрацией и посмотрите данные с формы приходят или нет

Comment: В контроллере с регой `dd($request->all());` что там приходит? И какая ошибка возникает вообще?

Comment: в том то и проблема что ошибки нет, просто не добавляет, а при dd($request->all()); пишет array:5 [▼
  "_token" => "5egc8fH85N3J4hL06XEDhcHvGxoczTPYPa1pGz56"
  "name" => "user"
  "email" => "user@user.ru"
  "password" => "123"
  "password_confirmation" => "123"
]

Comment: в контроллере<br/> <code>trait RegistersUsers
{

    public function postRegister(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = $this->validator($request->all());
       
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $this->throwValidationException(
                $request, $validator
            );
        }
      
        Auth::login($this->create($request->all()));

        return redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
}
</code> <br/>срабатывает $validator->fails() но почему не пойму пока